# Smoothly change CSS animation mid-animation

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to transition smoothly from one half-completed CSS animation to the next one and I can't find a way to do it without a slight stutter. I have an infinite animation at very high speed that should gently slow down to a stop on click. Right now, I'm always getting a slight hickup while switching animations, likely partially because I need to wait for the next requestAnimationFrame before starting the next animation. Are there other options? Here's approximately what I'm doing:

```
function onClick(){
  // get current location of element
  var content = $(".content");
  var currentOffset = $(content[0]).css("top");

  // set property to stop jumping back to the beginning of current animation
  content.css({ top: currentOffset });

  // stop the current animation
  content.removeClass("anim-infinite");

  // update content based on current location
  // updateContent(currentOffset);

  // setup ease-out animation
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    content.addClass("anim-ease-out");
    content.css({ top: parseFloat(currentOffset) + 50  });    
  });
}
```

And here's the relevant CSS.

```
@keyframes "spin" {
  from { top: 0 };
  to { top: -200%; }
}
.anim-infinite{
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}
.anim-ease-out{
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

The distances and timespans are reasonable to maintain constant speed between the two animations and I'm using the relevant browser prefixes.

I get the same stutter when I use a "linear" timing function for the second animation. I tried setting an `animation-fill-mode:both`, without success. It appears to only affect animations that complete.

The stutter gets worse when I try to update the content based on the location of the content - which is dependent on when the animation gets stopped.

Comment: Could you please create a jsFiddle?

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net with your relevant code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to work out a jsFiddle that demos the problem, I found the source of most of the stutter. Anything that happens between removing the `anim-infinite` class and in the `requestAnimationFrame` can have a big perf impact, especially if it modifies the DOM in the `content` and causes the content to reflow. That's obvious in retrospect but the minor DOM updates had a bigger impact than expected.

I still have a slight occasional stutter but it's "good enough" for now.

For reference, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spfDc/5/).